# How to lookup a specific index in Array

Tags: java, arraylist

I have made a Array containing 40 Fields.

```
System.out.println("Opretter felter");
Field[] felterISpil = new Field[40];
for (int i = 0; i < felterISpil.length; i++) {
    felterISpil[i] = new Field(".felt", i);
}
felterISpil[0] = new Field("Start", 1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(felterISpil));
```

I want to know, how i can lookup the name of 4.felt (index 5) up. Below you can see the code, which is generating the 40 fields in my main class

My Field.java is the following

```
class Field{

private String name;
private int number;

public Field (String fieldname, int fieldnumber)
{
    this.name = fieldname;
    this.number= fieldnumber;
}

public String getFieldname(){
    return name;
}
public int getFieldnumber(){
    return number;
}

public String toString(){
    return number+name;
}
public boolean equals(Object obj){
   Field field = (Field) obj;
    return (number == field.number && name.equals(field.name));
}
}
```

Comment: where is your `ArrayList`?

Comment: This is not an ArrayList. It's an array. You access an array element using array[index]. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Thanks! My bad. Im new to Java. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean lookup name , the name instance field ?, simply use `felterISpil[4].getFieldName()` to retrive it?